# Exception when trying to list wsdls in wso2 greg

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I get an empty screen when I click Main / Metadata / List / WSDLs in the management console of WSO2 Governance Registry.

Any idea on how I can start  trouble-shooting?

It may have started in relation to when I imported some WSDL files, but I am not sure.

The following entry is written to the `wso2carbon.log`:

```
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-04-26 09:23:26,214]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2013-04-26 09:23:26,214+0200] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-04-26 09:23:26,500] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1] {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:398)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.stub.ManageGenericArtifactServiceStub.listContentArtifacts(ManageGenericArtifactServiceStub.java:992)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.clients.ManageGenericArtifactServiceClient.listContentArtifacts(ManageGenericArtifactServiceClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.jsp.generic.list_005fcontent_jsp._jspService(list_005fcontent_jsp.java:182)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:966)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:643)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:637)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(template_jsp.java:539)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:290)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:258)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:172)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils.buildOMElement(GovernanceUtils.java:883)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.wsdls.dataobjects.WsdlImpl.loadWsdlDetails(WsdlImpl.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.wsdls.dataobjects.WsdlImpl.<init>(WsdlImpl.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils.retrieveGovernanceArtifactByPath(GovernanceUtils.java:693)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.services.ManageGenericArtifactService.listContentArtifactsByName(ManageGenericArtifactService.java:291)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.services.ManageGenericArtifactService.listContentArtifacts(ManageGenericArtifactService.java:223)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2029)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1114)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 126 more
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-04-26 09:23:26,500] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1] {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:398)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.stub.ManageGenericArtifactServiceStub.listContentArtifacts(ManageGenericArtifactServiceStub.java:992)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.clients.ManageGenericArtifactServiceClient.listContentArtifacts(ManageGenericArtifactServiceClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.jsp.generic.list_005fcontent_jsp._jspService(list_005fcontent_jsp.java:182)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:966)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:643)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:637)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(template_jsp.java:539)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:290)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:258)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:172)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils.buildOMElement(GovernanceUtils.java:883)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.wsdls.dataobjects.WsdlImpl.loadWsdlDetails(WsdlImpl.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.wsdls.dataobjects.WsdlImpl.<init>(WsdlImpl.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils.retrieveGovernanceArtifactByPath(GovernanceUtils.java:693)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.services.ManageGenericArtifactService.listContentArtifactsByName(ManageGenericArtifactService.java:291)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.services.ManageGenericArtifactService.listContentArtifacts(ManageGenericArtifactService.java:223)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2029)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1114)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 126 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason. It was that I by accident included two hidden files in the wsdl zip file I imported: deskop.ini and vssver2.scc. Those had the character `[` which made the wso2 greg to go bananas.

Pew, I guess I should report this as a bug. The WSDL zip file handler in WSO2 GREG should not accept such files!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Exception I think there is a syntax error in a wsdl file... Hope there is a tag which is not properly written...

ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'

Thanks,

Mohan

Comment: thanks, but it was actual neither a wsdl nor a xsd which had this character, but another resource which got imported by accident together with a wsdl zip.